# Is possible to modulate the upper and lower sides of a carrier with two distict signals?

Tags: modulation, amplitude-modulation

I would like to modulate in amplitude the upper and lower sides of a carrier with two distinct signals. Would it be possible?
There is a specific name for this scheme of modulation?

The detection will be made using the sampled data (in the digital domain).

Comment: Sure, probably not going to be easy though. Probably would use two single sideband transmitter circuits synchronized to the same carrier signal.

Comment: what will DC blocking do to the result?

Comment: I think I should have said upper envelope and lower envelope modulation, as upper and lower carrier trend to direct the answers to sidebands topic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, look for ISB modulation (Independent side band modulation), the military used to do it carrying two separate message streams on the two sidebands.

I am not sure there is much benefit these days, but it is not much of a problem to do, two phasing method modulators and just sum the output before up conversion, easy.